# Select an object at random

Tags: java

How can I randomize the display of the cards that are in my images folder, rather than always displaying a certain card (e.g. `1.png`)?

Here is my code. I know how to randomize for numbers, but not in this situation using a set folder.

```
package java_gui;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Images extends JFrame {
    //create JLabels
    JLabel card1 = new JLabel();
    JLabel card2 = new JLabel();
    JLabel card3 = new JLabel();

    public Images(){
        //create GridLayout
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1,4,5,5));
        //set images
        card1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("image/card/card/1.png"));
        card2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("image/card/card/2.png"));
        card3.setIcon(new ImageIcon("image/card/card/3.png"));
        //add JLabels
        add(card1);
        add(card2);
        add(card3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is already a good algorithm for shuffling the elements of an array.  Look at the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Comment: Not only is there already an algorithm, it's baked right into `Collections.shuffle` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)).

Answer (score 1):

In order to randomize the images without repeating them you should first create an array with all the numbers of the images you need. The array would contain:

```
cardsArrayNumber = {1, 2, 3}
```

Then then shuffle it:

```
cardsArrayNumber = {3, 1, 2}
```

And then go through this array assigning the images:

```
 card1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("image/card/card/" + String.valueOf(array[0]) + ".png"));
 card2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("image/card/card/" + String.valueOf(array[1]) + ".png"));
 card3.setIcon(new ImageIcon("image/card/card/" + String.valueOf(array[2]) + ".png"));
```

Tip: It'll be better if your cards are part of an array and you start numbering images from 0, so that you could handle any number of images easily:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cardsArray.length; i++) {
    cardsArray[i].setIcon(new ImageIcon("image/card/card/" + String.valueOf(array[i]) + ".png"));
}
```

This is how to [shuffle](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util/coll_Shuffle.html) an array and the [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29).